# How can I load jQuery's plugins together with jQuery each time jQuery is required?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

The line `$("body").slimScroll();` throws error, because `slimScroll` is not defined. That is because `require.js` probably doesn't load automatically `shim` keys, if you are requiring any module, that is specified as dependency in `shim` (i think if i have `shim` `jquery.slimscroll` and its dependency is `jquery`, then when i require `jquery`, it automatically loads `jquery.slimscroll` - this behavior doesn't happen).

So the right way is call `define(['jquery', 'jquery.slimscroll') function ($) ...`, so require knows i need `jquery.slimscroll` and because it is in shim, it will be loaded a bit different, because it is not AMD compatible.

Problem is that if i have lot of `jquery plugins`, i need always pass all plugins that i need in `define` call. Is there any way, how to solve this type of annoying behavior and write just `define(['jquery'], function ($) ..`?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/bower',
    paths: {
        react: 'react/react-with-addons',
        jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery',
        'jquery-private': '../jquery-private',
        'jquery.slimscroll': 'jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            jquery: 'jquery-private',
        },
        'jquery-private': {
                jquery: 'jquery'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.slimscroll': ['jquery']
    }

});


require(['jquery'], function ($) {

    $("body").slimScroll();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the jquery plugins to the dependencies of your `jquery-private` module.

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery.slimscroll', ...], function (jQuery) {
    return jQuery.noConflict(true);
});
```

This way, when any module requires `jquery`, the plugins are also loaded at the same time.

I'm assuming that `jquery-private` is meant to load jQuery so that it does not conflict with other version of jQuery. That's what my example reflects above but it does not generally matter what the module actually does.

With this method you still need to have a `shim` configuration for each plugin that is not an AMD module. Moreover, your plugins will have to get a `map` setting just like for `jquery-private` to get the real `jquery` module. Otherwise, there will be a circular dependency.

Comment: ty, worked, but i need even add record to map, so jquery.slimscroll gets real jquery and not jquery-private, otherwise there is circ dependency and it freezes my browser